# Can collisionmode be set to nothing?

Tags: swift, uicollisionbehavior

UiCollisionBehavior has four collision modes: 
1. Items
2. Boundaries
3. Init(rawValue: UInt)
4. Everything

Is it possible to set collisionmode to nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UICollisionBehaviorMode` is an [option set](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/optionset), which means you can pass an 'empty array' (`[]`) if you don't want any options.